# android parcelable string array

Tags: android, string, arraylist, bundle, parcel

I have

```
ArrayList<String> ids = ArrayList<String>();
```

What would be the cleanest way to make it Parceleable? Apparently String itself is not parcelable, so `Parcel.writeList(ids)` is not working.

I was thinking to either parcelize `ArrayList<Uri>`  or put array contents into a `Bundle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your list to String[] and use [Parcel.writeStringArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeStringArray%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29). Example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Comment: What about [Parcel.writeStringList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeStringList(java.util.List<java.lang.String>))?

Answer (score 3):

This isnt parcelizing, but to put it in a bundle:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("key",ids);
```